# How to use 'show' property in PowerBI custom visual

Tags: powerbi, formatting, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm trying to develop custom PowerBI visuals and am stuck at formatting. I can add 'show' property along other properties like here: [custom show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maBB1.png) but not next
to a card name like with standard visuals [Standard visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWDyx.png).

I don't see any solutions in documentations that would work for me. Any suggestions how I can correct this?

Below is corresponding part of jason and settings.ts I'm using.

```
    "objects":{
        "bars": {
            "properties": {
                "show": {
                    "type": {"bool": true}
                },
                "upColor":{
                    "type": {
                        "fill": {
                            "solid": {
                                "color": true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "downColor":{
                    "type": {
                        "fill": {
                            "solid": {
                                "color": true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "gapWidth":{
                    "type": {
                        "numeric":true
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

settings.ts :

```
class BarsSettings extends FormattingSettingsCard {
    // public show: boolean;
    public show = new formattingSettings.ToggleSwitch({
        name: "show",
        displayName: "show?",
        value: true
    });
    public upBarColor = new formattingSettings.ColorPicker({
        name: "upColor",
        displayName: "up bars color",
        value: { value: "green" }
    });
    public downBarColor = new formattingSettings.ColorPicker({
        name: "downColor",
        displayName: "down bars color",
        value: { value: "red" }
    });
    public gapWidth = new formattingSettings.NumUpDown({
        name: "gapWidth",
        displayName: "Gap width in % of a bar",
        value: 200
    });

    public name: string = "bars";
    public displayName: string = "Bars";

    slices: Array<FormattingSettingsSlice> = [this.show, this.gapWidth, this.downBarColor, this.upBarColor];
}

export class VisualSettings extends FormattingSettingsModel {
    // Create formatting settings model formatting cards
    public bars: BarsSettings = new BarsSettings();

    public cards:  Array<FormattingSettingsCard> = [this.bars];
}
```